# Use of list in for loop

Tags: r, for-loop

I am in trouble with a part of my code. I'm a beginner and i tried to make a for loop with a list to construct different data.frame. Let's see

```
df<-data

head(data)

col1    col2    col3
A       1       13
A       2       34
A       2       46
B       1       23
D       3       56  
B       2       31


df_a<-data[which(data$col1=="A")
df_b<-data[which(data$col1=="B")
df_c<-data[which(data$col1=="C")
df_d<-data[which(data$col1=="D")

list<-c("_a","_b","_c","_d")
for (i in list){
    paste0("df",i,"1")<-data(which(paste0("df",i)$col2==1))
    paste0("df",i,"2")<-data(which(paste0("df",i)$col2==2))
    paste0("df",i,"3")<-data(which(paste0("df",i)$col2==3))
```

In this case the aim is to construct different dataframe with my original dataframe. In this context it could look like a little tricky but i'm not using exactly this way even if the syntax is similar.

The problem is with adjunction of the paste name of data frame and the "$". R return an error message :

> ```
> Error in which(paste0("df", i, "1")$col2 == 1) : 
>   erreur d'évaluation de l'argument 'x' lors de la sélection d'une 
> méthode pour la fonction 'which' : Error in paste0("df", 
> i, "1")$col2 : 
>   $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
> ```

Do you have an idea to resolve this problem ?

Comment: You're missing closing brackets in your code, it should be something like `df_a<-data[which(data$col1=="A"), ]`, and the same for b, c, and d.

Comment: Just `Filter(nrow, split(df, list(df$col1, df$col2)))` should be enough

Answer (score 1):

If I'm interpreting the question correctly, in order to do what you need exactly, you need a combination of `assign`, `eval`, and `parse`:

```
df <- data.frame(col1 = c("A", "A", "A", "B", "D", "B"), 
                 col2 = c(1, 2, 2, 1, 3, 2),
                 col3 = c(13 ,34, 46, 23, 56, 31))

df_a<-df[which(df$col1=="A"), ]
df_b<-df[which(df$col1=="B"), ]
df_c<-df[which(df$col1=="C"), ]
df_d<-df[which(df$col1=="D"), ]

list <- c("_a","_b","_c","_d")

for (i in list) {
  assign(paste0("df", i, "1"), df[eval(parse(text = paste0("which(df", i, "$col2 == 1)"))), ])
  assign(paste0("df", i, "2"), df[eval(parse(text = paste0("which(df", i, "$col2 == 2)"))), ])
  assign(paste0("df", i, "3"), df[eval(parse(text = paste0("which(df", i, "$col2 == 3)"))), ])
}
```

If your goal is to perform operations on these different groups of data, you may want to look into the package `dplyr`'s `group_by()`, which provides a much cleaner way to perform grouped operations.

Another, much cleaner, way to do this is using the `split()` function to store each of the splits in one list:

```
split_dfs <- split(df, df$col1)
split_dfs <- lapply(split_dfs, function(x) split(x, x$col2))
```

Comment: Thanks to everybody. This solution solve the problem ! And yes the last proposition is clearly cleaner that mine... I will remember this function next time

Answer (score 1):

```
df <- read.table(text="col1    col2    col3
A       1       13
A       2       34
A       2       46
B       1       23
D       3       56  
B       2       31", header=T)



library(dplyr)
letters <- c("A", "B", "C", "D")
for(i in 1:3){
for(j in seq_along(letters)){
  assign(paste0("df_",tolower(letters[j]), i), df %>% filter(col1==letters[j]) %>% select(i) )
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

is this what you're after? Be sure to close your brackets and clue up on the assign function.

```
col1 = c("A","A","A","B","D","B")
col2 = c(1,2,2,1,3,2)
col3 = c(13,34,46,34,56,31)

data = cbind(col1,col2,col3)
data = as.data.frame(data)


list<-c("_a","_b","_c","_d")

for (i in list){
  assign(paste0("df",i,"1"),data[which(data$col1 =="A" & data$col2 ==1),])
  assign(paste0("df",i,"2"),data[which(data$col1 =="B" & data$col2 ==2),])
  assign(paste0("df",i,"3"),data[which(data$col1 =="C" & data$col2 ==3),])
  }
```